# Discrete Relation Properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I can not get a grasp on Relations. Any help would be great.

Prove that if R is a symmetric relation, so is R^2.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that $S=R^2.$ We want to show that $S$ is symmetric, using the fact that $R$ is symmetric.

So, suppose $a\: S\: b.$ By definition of $S,$ there is some $c$ such that $a\: R\: c$ and $c\: R\: b.$ But $R$ is symmetric, so what can we conclude? What follows from that?